# C# CUSTOM VKP80iii Paper Ejector/Paper Cut

Tags: c#, printing, pos

I am using RawPrinterHelper class to print on a Custom VKP80iii. 
I can print but I cant Cut and Eject the Paper. Does any have a code which Cuts and Ejects the Paper?

I tried a lot of Commands but none worked.

The last command I found but also didn´t work was :

```
string cutpaper = "" + Convert.ToChar(29) + Convert.ToChar(101)  + Convert.ToChar(3) + Convert.ToChar(32);
RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName, cutpaper);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the kind support of Custom, the solution is writing the sequence:

```
this.WriteBytes(new byte[6]
      {
       (byte) 28,
       (byte) 80,
       (byte) 5,
       (byte) 1,
       (byte) 69,
       (byte) 5
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

just to add a few explanations here, this is a command you can find in the VPK80III manual ! It's called "Ticket Presentation" ("FS" P)

Only problem is that we were looking for "ejection" or "cut" keywords so we overlooked this one, which proved to be the only valid answer to our need !

[Screen of the VPK80III Doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8Q5J.png)